# How do I write out many variables in a type in short hand, from a JSON response, in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

I have  a relatively trivial question, say I need to create a new type from a JSON Response

My  JSON response (lets call it Label Response) is as follows

```
{
id1: "someString"
someField: "someString"
someMoreFields: "someString"
EvenMorefields: "someString"
EvenMoreMoreFields: "someString"
SoManyManyFields: "someString"
EndlessFields: "someString"
}
```

Now if I choose to create a type from this response it would be as follows (correct me if i am wrong)

```
export type LabelResponse =
      {
       Fields: string;
       FieldsMore:string;
       MoreMoreFields:string;
       MoreMoreMoreFields:string;
      }
```

**This is very verbose** Since the more IDs, I have the more fields I will need and all the Ids are of the same type.

Is there a way to possible write this in short hand, for example, in my function parameter, instead of declaring a type for it

For example instead of

```
function myFunction(label:LabelResponse)
```

Would it be possible to declare my type in the parameter brackets ? Like this:

```
function myFunction(label:DeclareMyTypeHereSomehow?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type include a string key and a value key like so:

```
type LabelResponse = Record<string, string>

const data: LabelResponse = {
    id1: "someString",
    id2: "someString",
    someRandomString: "someString",
    someWeirdString: "someString",
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgIwgGwEoQM5gPYDsPQC8U6AxtgE4AmAPBsBQJa4DmANFPU6wHwBQfcvmBQqcYHABcsRCnRY8BKMQDefKBqiMqARmkAiDNgC2EAMoNmLfW3WbtAJgNHTF7tdubOJiKji4qEzcrZx9g1hs7DRcIAHUIRmpwllDXSwjbAF8gA)

Comment: Yes, but I would need to do that for similar JSON Responses, i am trying to not clutter my code, by just declaring a type in the parameter, and assigning that this type contains many id's which are all strings.

I am not sure if Tscript has this funcitonality.

Comment: Do you mean other responses? If they are having the same schema, then you can re-use `LabelResponse` for them too.

Comment: If i have many many IDs, lets say 100. I would need to add those IDs into my type wouldnt I?

What if the field was different for example env, I just need it to check that whatever the field IT MUST BE A string.

Comment: Yes! With that `Record<string, string>` you can put whatever string you'd like to as a key. Try it

Comment: I updated the answer for more clarification, also try out the playground

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the type definition using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) like following:

```
export type LabelResponse = { [K in `id${1|2|3|4}`]: string; }
```

This will give a type as:

```
type LabelResponse = {
    id1: string;
    id2: string;
    id3: string;
    id4: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAyBDARsANgJWAGdIA7I1AXgCgBvauOAbQGk4BLUuAA3YBMAJLQCMAHwBMogMyiALAF9uAXQBccIjCicA5gG5q8oA).

---

Or if you don't care about the actual range, you can use `id${number}`:

```
export type LabelResponse = { [K in `id${number}`]: string; }

// errors since key doesn't start with id
const x:  LabelResponse = {
  'x1': 'hello'
}

// works
const y: LabelResponse = {
  'id2': 'world'
}

// not works since it expects a number after id
const z: LabelResponse = {
  'idx': '!'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMA8AcHsCcAupEE9rlAGQIYCNwAbAJXAGc4A7MzAXgCgRQBvRsUUAbQGlQBLSqAAGfACYASZgEYAPgCYZAZhkAWAL5CAugC5QZRPAEBzANxtQa+vShwkKdJlwES5KjVANWHHv0EiJzJQArgC2BPAaOnoGxmaW9ADGsNTIkLrY+ESkFMnutCz0HADkkFJFukUAFkSEsEX08UkpoKi6TlmuuXQFxWJy5aBFAO4IhKL1jbnIAF5tmS451N1eg2KQA0UAhBNAA)

---

If you don't care about the key at all, then you can just do:

```
type LabelResponse = {
  [K: string]: string
}
```

Comment: This was an example, the fields will not only be called  id1,id2,idx it can be anything, i just need to make sure compiler checks that the result of the fields are always strings

Comment: In that case, you can just do `type LabelResponse = {
  [K: string]: string
}`. Updated the answer.